# Why isn't this a memory leak? Or is it? Deleting base class pointer without virtual destructors

Tags: c++, inheritance, memory-leaks, virtual-destructor

I've been meddling around, testing for memory leaks with Intel Inspector, when I noticed something that should not be. I inherit from std::vector which is not supposed to have a virtual destructor, I have an extra member in the derived class, I do dynamic memory allocation on it, in main I create a derived class on the heap, cast to base class, call delete... and no memory leak is detected??? By all logic, I should get a memory leak.

```
template <typename T>
class DynamicArray : public std::vector<T> {
public:    
    DynamicArray() : children(nullptr) {
        children = new int(50);
    }
    ~DynamicArray() {
        if (children) delete children;
    }
    DynamicArray& operator<<(const T& value)
    {
        push_back(value);
        return *this;
    }
private:
    int *children;
};


int main() {
    DynamicArray<int> *pArray = new DynamicArray<int>;
    (*pArray) << 4 << 5;
    static_cast<std::vector<int>*>(pArray);
    delete pArray;
}
```

Comment: Especially with issues related to this, it is good practice to declare your destructors `virtual` (although it is most important for this to be true of the base class)

Comment: Inheriting from STL containers is bad, mmkay? Use composition or non-member non-friend template functions if you must extend one of them.

Comment: @AJG85 - yeah, yeah, like alcohol and tobacco aren't bad, yet it didn't stop people from going beyond using and abusing those. I only plan to use my derived class very responsibly, thus the extensive testing for potential problems.

Comment: @ddriver Thus the south park reference, however while it can be fun and even interesting to get totally blitzed there are consequences to be aware of that will **always** eventually bite you. Same thing applies to code that flirts with undefined behavior.

Comment: `DynamicArray() : children(nullptr) { children = new int(50); }` -- why? Why not `DynamicArray() : children(new int(50)) { }`?

Comment: @AJG85: In this case, I don't even intend to use polymorphism at all, I can't figure out a reason why I would do that, besides toying, which is what I am doing with this code - just pushing beyond the limits of the reasonable so I can learn.

Comment: @ildjarn - that is what I'd do if it was a real class, not just some fooling around :) In my actual class hierarchy I start with a nullptr because children are attached to the object afterwards, not in the constructor.

Comment: Inheriting from an STL container object isn't just flirting with undefined behavior.  In the baseball vernacular where flirting with UB is the equivalent of getting to 1st base, this is a home run.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`pArray` is still of type `DynamicArray<int>` and wiil call the right destructor, this would likely leak:

```
std::vector<int>* wrong = static_cast<std::vector<int>*>(pArray);
delete wrong;
```

edit: as Ben Voigt correctly mentioned, this last code snippet actually undefined behavior since the destructor of `std::vector` is not virtual. So it is not even guaranteed that this will leak

Comment: It's undefined behavior, potentially more disastrous than a memory leak.

Comment: You are correct, with a new pointer I have a 4 byte leak. Thanks for clarifying, I learn something new every day.

Comment: @BenVoigt: what exactly is the undefined behaviour? I will gladly updated my question, but I'd rather give an explanation as why it is undefined behaviour.

Comment: Deleting an object through a pointer to a base class that doesn't have a virtual destructor is undefined behavior, as per the standard.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore, thank you, I was always under the impression it would just call the base-class destructor (well-defined that is). I added it to the answer as it is more correct.

Comment: "In the first alternative (`delete` *object*), if the static type of the object to be deleted is different from its dynamic type, the static type shall be a base class of the dynamic type of the object to be deleted and the static type shall have a virtual destructor or the behavior is undefined."  5.3.5p3

Comment: Still, in my case it does call the base class destructor, thus the 4 byte leak from the int.

Comment: The `static_cast` is superfluous anyway, an upcast is an implicit conversion.

Answer (score 5):

This expression has no side-effects:

```
static_cast<std::vector<int>*>(pArray);
```

In your code, the `delete` and `new` actually match perfectly.

---

Also, this line allocates ONE `int`, so you may not notice it in your memory analysis:

```
children = new int(50);
```

Comment: yep, one int is enough, it's just for testing purpose